# Amateur Question? Would I do a two-tailed test and then find Pearson's R?

Tags: correlation

Currently trying to find the correlation of two different datasets using a null and alternative hypothesis. Is it sufficient to report this using the p-value generated from pearson's R or will a two-tailed test also have to be completed in order to full illustrate the negative/positive relationship.

Currently using R for analysis.

Comment: It depends on how you set up the test. If there is only reason for you to test for positive and not negative correlation, i.e you set the alternative to be pearson correlation > 0, or vice versa, then it is ok for you to set alternative = "greater" in R.

Can you briefly explain more about what you are testing?

Comment: Thanks for the response I currently have a null and alternative hypothesis and need to merely show if there is a significant relationship (either negative or positive). I then think the two tailed test would be appropriate but should I also use the Pearson's R to show strength, if so how should I present this?

Comment: I would write something like X was strongly associated with Y (r=.., P=..), maybe something like in https://www.nature.com/articles/ijo201113#Sec10